# Showing a certain element of a commutative ring is invertible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $E$ be an algebra over a commutative ring $A$ with basis $(e,i)$ of type $(\alpha,\beta)$: i.e. $e^2=1$, $ei=ie=i$ and $i^2=\alpha e+\beta i$.

Suppose $(e,\gamma e+\delta i)$ is another basis of $E$ for $\gamma,\delta\in A$. I want to show that this implies that $\delta$ is invertible. The author suggests considering the linear mapping $\pi:E\rightarrow E/Ae$. Clearly, $\pi(i)$ is a basis of the module $E/Ae$. The author further comments that $\pi(\delta i)$ is also a basis and that this shows that $\delta$ is invertible.

I cannot see why $\pi(\delta i)$ is a basis of $E/Ae$. Take $x\in E$. Then $x=\xi e+\eta\gamma e+\eta\delta i=(\xi+\eta\gamma)e+\eta\delta i$ and so $\pi(x)=\eta\pi(\delta i)$. This shows that $\pi(\delta i)$ generates $E/Ae$. Now try to show independence; suppose $\eta\pi(\delta i)=0$: then $\eta\delta i=\xi e$ and so $\eta\delta=\xi=0$. But why does this imply that $\eta=0$?

Even if both $\pi(i)$ and $\pi(\delta i)$ are taken to be bases of $E/Ae$, why does it follows from this that $\delta$ is invertible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose that when you say *basis* you mean as an $A$-module.

The trick is to write the equality $\eta\delta i=\xi e$ you found as $\eta\left(\gamma e+\delta i\right)=\left(\gamma+\xi\right)e$. This implies that $\eta=0$ because $\left(e,\gamma e+\delta i\right)$ is a basis of $E$.

Now, you can write $\pi\left(i\right)=a\pi\left(\delta i\right)$ for some $a\in A$ because $\left\{\pi\left(\delta i\right)\right\}$ is a basis of $E/Ae$. In particular, $a\delta=1$ because $\left\{\pi\left(i\right)\right\}$ is also a basis of $E/Ae$, and $\pi$ is $A$-linear.